# Implement a conditional state machine for a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine, aasm

I have a rails model called `Creative` that implements a workflow using the `aasm` gem. Currently my model has just one workflow implemented in it.

I have a business scenario that will require me to implement another workflow in the same model which which will be activated if a boolean value on the model is `true`.

I see 2 approaches that could be viable options

- Create a new model that uses the same table name as `Creative` and implement the workflow there
- Implement the workflow in the same model using a separate column to store the states for the second workflow and use its method depending on my boolean value

What would be a good design that could be implemented here?

I understand this is a very open ended question and would love to get suggestions if anyone has come across such a scenario

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work.

```
event :promote do
  transitions :from => [:pending], :to => :in_progress, :guard => :boolean_check?
  transitions :from => [:pending], :to => :done
end

event :complete do
  transitions :from => [:in_progress], :to => :done, :guard => :boolean_check?
end

private

def boolean_check?
  self.boolean_column
end
```

If the boolean value is true the flow will be

```
pending > in_progress > done
```

else

```
pending > done
```

**NOTE:** This might get complex if let's say you have 3-4 workflows.

It's ok till you have 2 workflows

Comment: Thanks for this. This is something I could try out. Unfortunately the solution provided works in case of a small number of events. The workflow we require has quite a lot of different events and a guard would have to be added on each event and newer events would have to be added to the same workflow which would make it a non-readable piece of code. Thanks again though. Ill try this